# webview save editable

Tags: android

how to save editable content loaded of local storage?
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/table.html")

```
<table id="customers">
    <tbody><tr class="alt"><th> </th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt"><td>1</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>asdasd</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>153213 </td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>253625213</td>
        <td contenteditable='true'>026426</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' >asdasd</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first injecting a JavaScript-accessible POJO using `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`.  Your Android POJO would have the code to save the data.  Then set up a JavaScript event listener to fire the POJO method.  You could listen for a Done button click from the user or perhaps the new HTML5 `input` event.